# How to test ipa app(from expo) on devices before publish to app store

Tags: xcode, react-native, expo, ipa

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A5I8w.png)

I built ipa file with react native expo and i attempted testing on devices.
I connected my own iphone to mac and used xcode + button for upload.
But i got a this message that "Unable to install (appname)" . Can I test the app(that built by expo) on the my own device?? I already registered apple developer accounts at yesterday.

Comment: You should look at the "How to ask a question" link https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . Code that you have tried and a sample product would help https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

According to a thread on developer.apple.com, this issue got resolved after the iOS version 13.4. Please review your developer account and it's license, as it usually happen with non-paid developer account.

Quick way to testing your app, upload your ipa on diawi.com and with QR Scan or Share link, you can download and install app on your device.

Comment: I already purchased apple developer license and got an email from apple.

Comment: What is your provisioning profile settings? is it set to auto or you are installing it manually? Miss-matched or incompatible profiles can also lead to this issue.